# Custom tab bar setting the frame and position

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c

I'm currently in the process of making my custom tab bar. It's working fine, the way I did it was by hiding the default bar. I have my images prepared, the on and off ones. 
There seems to be an implementing of these into the main concept by using:

btn3.frame = CGRectMake(240, 430, 80, 50);

The number combination is unique for each CGRectMake. I have done it, but i'm using 3 buttons on the bar. This tutorial uses four. What should I set the number combination for each CGRectMake if i'm using 3 buttons and not 4. Because I assume that the combos are proportional to each other depending on how many tabs there are. All it is, is setting the frame size and position of the button/tab.

I used these for my tabs, but I got a gap in between.
btn1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 430, 80, 50);
btn2.frame = CGRectMake(160, 430, 80, 50);
btn3.frame = CGRectMake(240, 430, 80, 50);

http://www.rumexit.co.uk/2010/11/how-to-customise-the-tab-bar-uitabbar-in-an-iphone-application-part-2-of-2/

it's in the fourth box on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Pseudocode.
    int numButtons = 3;
    float buttonWidth = self.view.frame.size.width / numButtons;

    btn1.frame = CGRectMake(0 * buttonWidth, 430, buttonWidth, 50); btn2.frame = CGRectMake(1 * buttonWidth, 430, buttonWidth, 50); btn3.frame = CGRectMake(2 * buttonWidth, 430, buttonWidth, 50);
```

Comment: I tried this and I got the error 'CGRect' has no member named 'width'.

Comment: It's pseudo code since I don't know exactly where you are calling this from. Try self.view.frame.size.width.